# How can I convert $users value obtained form database using eloquent model to $finalVaue?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

```
 $users = User::select(['name','value'])->orderBy('value','DESC')->get();
```

I want to convert above $users value into `$finalValue` as below

```
  $finalValue=  array(
       (object) array( 'name' => 'name1', 'value' => 10 ),
       (object) array( 'name' => 'name2', 'value' => 7 ),
       (object) array( 'name' => 'name3', 'value' => 6 ),
       (object) array( 'name' => 'name4', 'value' => 3 ),
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `foreach`.

```
$finalValue = [];
foreach($users as $user) {
    $finalValue[] = ['name' => $user->name, 'value' => $user->value];
}
```

If you want to cast every element of the `$finalValue` array, add `(object)` infront of every array appending, like so:

`$finalValue[] = (object)['name' => $user->name, 'value' => $user->value];`

Though I don't see how this can be useful.

Docs for [foreach](http://php.net/manual/bg/control-structures.foreach.php) & [type juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php)

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily be done by using eloquent `lists`

```
 $finalValue = User::orderBy('value','DESC')->lists('name', 'value');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use toArray();

```
$users = User::select(['name','value'])
->orderBy('value','DESC')
->get()
->toArray();
```